# Serverless Framework custom lambda authorizer is not being triggered

Tags: lambda, frameworks, authorization, token, serverless

So I am using the Serverless Framework and the custom lambda authorizer is not being triggered. When I check the function that should be authorized, the API Gateway console says it has no authorization. I also can't find my authorization function under Authorizers. Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
loginUser:
    handler: loginUser.loginUser
    module: src/functions/loginFunction
    events:
      - http:
          path: /user/login
          method: post
          request:
            schema:
              application/json: ${file(src/schema/loginUser_request.json)}

  getCats:
    handler: catCrud.getCats
    module: src/functions/catCrud
    events:
      - http: 
          path: /cat
          method: get
          authoirzer:
            name: authorizeFunc
            identitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
            type: token
  authorizeFunc:
    handler: authorizeFunc.authorizeFunc
    module: src/functions/loginFunction
```

P.S. I am not sure if this is of any value, but I am using the serverless-python-requirements for packaging up my lambdas and the authorizeFunc is sharing the same module with the loginFunction because they have the same libs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled `authorizer` in the `events` section of your `serverless.yml`.

Try:

```
  getCats:
    handler: catCrud.getCats
    module: src/functions/catCrud
    events:
      - http: 
          path: /cat
          method: get
          authorizer:
            name: authorizeFunc
            identitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
            type: token
```

Comment: Wow. I apologize for the silly mistake. It never occurred to me it would be a typo because it was deploying fine with no errors. I would have spent the day searching for an answer. Thank you! :d